# What's the analytical solution of linear regression under L1loss

Tags: regression

It is a interview question, we know that for a simple linear regression:

$$\min\limits_{\beta}\sum(y-(\beta x))^2,$$
and
$$\min\limits_{\beta'}\sum(x-(\beta' y))^2,$$

Let's assume the sample is centralized:

$$\bar{x} = \bar{y} = 0.$$

Then We have a conclusion:

$$\beta*\beta' = \dfrac{S^2_{xy}}{S_{xx}S_{yy}} = \rho^2_{xy} = R-Squared.$$

If we use L1 loss to replace L2 loss i.e. $$\min\limits_{\theta}\sum|y-(\beta x))|,$$
What's the conclusion of $\beta*\beta'?$ Actually I am not sure if there is still a analytical solution? How about for Lp?

**Edit:**

I confused that in simple regression,  if we consider `no constant term`: $y = \beta x$ and `no centralization` of data, we can see that, the R-squared is
$$R^2 = 1-\dfrac{RSS}{TSS} = \dfrac{ESS}{TSS} = \dfrac{(\sum x_iy_i)^2}{\sum (x_i)^2\sum (y_i)^2} = \cos^2\theta,$$
which is the cos (square) of the projection angle of $y = (y_1,\cdots,y_N).$ Here we use the decomposition:
$$\sum y_i^2 (SST) = \sum \hat{y}_i^2 (ESS) + \sum (y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2 (RSS).$$

My question is that:

Is the conclusion $R^2 = \cos^2\theta$ still true in the multiple linear regression when there is `no constant term` and `no centralization` of data?

Comment: What is $R-Sqaure$? Are you asking what would $\theta\theta'$ be if it was $L_1$ norm?

Comment: @gunes yes, pls see my update

Comment: Your conclusion is not generally correct: you implicitly assume both $y$ and $x$ have been standardized to unit variance.  What assertion, then, are you trying to generalize?

Comment: @whuber sorry let me add the constant term, pls see my update

Comment: It's *still* not correct: the standardization is crucial.

Comment: @whuber if we assume the sample matrix is non-degenerate, then $\beta*\beta' = \dfrac{S^2_{xy}}{S_{xx}S_{yy}} = \rho^2_{xy}.$ And the R-Squared is also the correlation (square) of $X,Y.$ right?

Comment: No, $\beta\beta^\prime$ is not the squared correlation!  When $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary, the coefficient estimate can be literally any number -- but you know $R^2$ cannot exceed $1.$  $\beta$ is the correlation when both $x$ and $y$ have unit variance.

Comment: @whuber now I agree with you, without centralization, it is not R-squared. But it is sample correlation $\dfrac{S^2_{xy}}{S_{xx}S_{yy}},$ right? Let's add the condition: $\bar{x} = \bar{y} = 0$ and continue the quesiton.

Comment: @whuber I updated the question with the confusion on R-Squared.